# Handling runnable function in android studio JAVA [count down timer]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Consider an application, it will count down from 60 to 0 at intervals of 1 second.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int time;
    TextView timeDisplay;
    private Handler handler new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedinstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedinstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        time = 60;
        timeDisplay (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.timeDisplay);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimer);
        handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 1000); 
    }

    private Runnable updateTimer = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        
           // somthing here
        }
    };
  }
```

I try to implement a count down timer like this but I am very new to android studio and java and did not really know how to implement this. Hence any comment will be very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried **CountDownTimer**? You could read more information here
[CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Comment: I was told to implement in this way. But thank you for your comment